# Firestore database java add where condition before get collection

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Firestore database for my web application. When I query documents from a collection I need to append a where condition. Is there any method available to append specific conditions before fetch CollectionReference?

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = dbFirestore.collection("collectionName").someMethod("Where conditions to fetch specific documents")
```

Or any other options to send a full query with conditions from **Java or Spring** to **Firestore** and get results? I don't want to have database codes in my front-end designs. If no other option, I would end up using javascript to do so. But it would be not a proper design.

```
Query query = dbFirestore.collection("collectionName").whereEqualTo("colmn1", "value").whereEqualTo("column2", "value");
```

How to iterate values from query (com.google.cloud.firestore.Query) object?

Comment: Can you explain 'append specific conditions'? You need to use those methods and build the query over a CollectionReference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the result of the following query:

```
Query query = dbFirestore.collection("collectionName").whereEqualTo("colmn1", "value").whereEqualTo("column2", "value");
```

You have to call [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get()), and then attach a listener, as you can see in the following lines of code:

```
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document != null) {
                    //Get the data out from the document.
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

If you're using Java for a Non-Android project, then you should consider using the following lines of code:

```
ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> future = dbFirestore.collection("collectionName").get();
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = future.get();
List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.getDocuments();
ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : documents) {
    String docId = document.getId();
    ids.add(docId);
    System.out.println(docId);
    String name = document.getString("name");
    names.add(name);
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Comment: not using as a android approach. Its pure Java Web application. Unable to add listener method getting this error. The method addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>(){}) is undefined for the type ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot>. @Alex Mamo

Comment: In that case, please see my updated answer. Does it work that way?

Comment: I am having equivalent pojo object. It would be much better if I able to cast resultset to pojo.

Comment: Then call `document.toObject()` and convert it to the desired object.

Comment: Yes it converts to my pojo. Strangely both,  If I add from casted object.getField() , document.getString("columnName"); prints value in log.debug(). When I try to add this String result to my ArrayList collection, my list become blank or empty. And I inspected my list.add() returns empty rather than false or true flag. @Alex Mamo

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. So when you call `object.getField()` are you getting the correct value? If yes, what the issue?

Comment: [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) return a boolean. It **cannot** return empty nor blank. Try to log the size of the list instead. What is the result?